# Angular translate - return value of .determinePreferredLanguage() for drop down menu

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have created a drop down menu of language choices using angular-translate.
 I want the default language choice to be the value obtained from `$translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage()`. I cannot figure out how to access this value. 
The code below works in regards to allowing the user to change the language, but there is nothing displayed on the drop down menu by default. 
I know that `"{{$translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage()}}"` is wrong, as it's the function itself and not what it's returning. However, I cannot figure out how to display the user's default language.

```
<select ng-model="langKey" ng-change="changeLanguage(langKey)">
    <option value="">{{$translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage()}}</option>
    <option ng-repeat="language in languages" value="{{language.abbr}}">{{language.lang}}</option>
</select>
```

In my helperService.js file, I have the languages defined as follows:

```
helper.languages = [
 {abbr: "ar", lang: "العربية"},
 {abbr: "zh-cn", lang: "简体中文"},
 {abbr: "zh-tw", lang: "中國，繁體（台灣)"},
 {abbr: "en", lang: "English"},
 {abbr: "fr", lang: "Français"},
 {abbr: "de", lang: "Deutsch"},
 {abbr: "it", lang: "Italiano"},
 {abbr: "ja", lang: "日本語"},
 {abbr: "ko", lang: "한국어"},
 {abbr: "pt-br", lang: "Português (Brasil)"},
 {abbr: "ru", lang: "Pусский"},
 {abbr: "es", lang: "Español"}
];
```

So, if the user's default is 'en', it should display 'English' in the drop down by default. Or, if it's 'de', it should say 'Deutsch'. Any suggestions?